# Accessibility in a custom Swing control which apes a native one?

Tags: java, swing, accessibility

I have a Swing custom control which serves an almost identical function to a JLabel. It's not accessible by default for people who use assistive technology, like a screen reader. I'm working on the [Megamek GitHub Project](https://github.com/MegaMek/megamek/issues/1288), and trying to figure out how to associate the PMSimpleLabel class with other objects, as in the JLabel class's setLabelFor method.

The approach taken so far seems to be to more or less ape the JLabel's accessibility implementation. I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it, there seem to be some elements in the latter I'm not understanding.

Comment: The only guidance that I know of for making custom Swing components accessible is in [Building Custom Accessible Component](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W10ef84c59396_40fb_aa66_a05ad699cda6/page/5.0%20Building%20Custom%20Accessible%20Components) in the *IBM guidelines for writing accessible applications using 100% pure java™* (2004).

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be largely because of the custom components. The AccessibleJComponent class has a fallback mechanism to name controls which don't ohterwise have accessible names, but this is hard-coded to look for a JLabel and not a custom label class.

There are a few work-arounds for this, such as modifying the get/setAccessibleName methods, or switching to using the accessible description instead.

The solution in the long term is probably to use regular Swing components where possible